# Downloading files in a queue using download manager in android?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am downloading multiple file same time with download manager. but my problem is download manager start download all files with same time i need to start download file one by one in queue means first item download first than all one by one.

> DownloadManager.Java

```
if(downloaddata.size()>0){              
   for(int i=0;i<downloaddata.size();i++){
        downloadFiles(downloaddata.get(i).getFile_id(),downloaddata.get(i).getFile_url(),"OTHER");
   }
}   


 public void downloadFiles(String myid,String myurl,String type){
        createFolder();
        String fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(myurl, null, null);
        Uri uri=Uri.parse(myurl);
        request=new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
        request.setTitle(myid);
        request.setMimeType(type);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/peakmedia",fileName);            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN);
        downloadReference=downloadManager.enqueue(request);
        downloadlist.add(downloadReference);

    }
```

Comment: use intent service and submit it task of downloading files.. it will handle it in a queue .. you dont have to worry about executing it in parallel ..

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Dont understand a word.

Comment: You could use your own `IntentService` for download of files , instead of using DownloadManager.

Comment: Make downloadManager.maxParallelDownloads = 1.
then next item will automatically added to queue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DownloadManager broadcasts [`ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE), so you can just request the next file to download when the BroadcastReceiver receives success for previous file.

Comment: How will I update the progress of these downloads on my home screen? I am using manifest-declared receiver. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance